# jquery : Not selector not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Something makes me crazy, I use the following code (from [ajaxUpload](https://github.com/funkatron/ajax-upload) to upload images :

Here is the html :

```
<div class="slide">
    <span id="close_btn1" class="del"><a href="#" onclick="return false;">Delete</a></span>
</div>
<div class="slide">
    <span id="close_btn2" class="del"><a href="#" onclick="return false;">Delete</a></span>
</div>
```

and the js :

```
 $('.slide').each(function(){
    new AjaxUpload($(this),{
        action:"upload",
        name:'userfile',
        onSubmit:function(file, extension){  
            do some work..
        },
        onComplete: function(file, response) {
            do some work..
        }
    });
});

$("#close_btn1").click(function(){
  do some work...
});
```

Images are uploaded when I click on any "slide" div : OK

But if I click on the link Delete : this is the same behavior than if I click on "slide", and the link doesn't work : KO

I would like to exclude this link (class "del") from the for each condition.

I tried :

```
$('.slide').not('.del').each( ...
```

also :

```
new AjaxUpload($(this).not('.del'),{ ...
```

but it doesn't work..

Any idea?

Comment: `$(".slide *:not(.del)")` ?

Comment: Use `$('.del').on('click', function(e){ e.stopPropogation(); })`

Comment: Instead, explain what is your expected behaviour???

Comment: @charlietfl  the "return false" was to avoid the page scroll to top

Comment: Please read [what is XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) **and** [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). `and the link doesn't work` What does mean? What are you expecting it to do???

Comment: You can do this: `$(".del").click(false)` to apply a generic handler to the `.del` elements that will preventDefault and stopPropagation.

Comment: @squint can you detail please?

Comment: @squint Well i didn't know this shorthand, quite useful indeed  (and documented, meaning it is publicly supported)

Comment: thanks but I tried evthg and still the same:(

Comment: @A.Wolff  about "the link doesn't works", I mean the code inside "#close_btn1" is not executed. And instead this is like I click anywhere on "slide". Without $('.slide')..each.. this link is working perfectly (it delete the picture).

Comment: Open your console and fix error. I don't know this plugin but looks like it doesn't support a jq object as first parameter but a string selector

Comment: @A.Wolff seems it support jquery object ($(this) as 1st param is understood) but not the Not selector and others probably

Answer (score -2):

What I think is happening: the $(this) is referring to the `a` element, not to the the `span`. Try to put the del class in the `a` element